# How to make a div element navigable by arrow keys when using JAWS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I would like to make a `div` element navigable by arrow keys when JAWS is running. The `div` should **not** be navigable using the `TAB` key; so using `tabindex` is not applicable.

Here is an example snippet of the html/reactjs structure.

```
const label1 = 'First label';
const label2 = 'Second label';
const prefix = 'Prefix';
const suffix = 'Suffix';

const screenReaderText = `${prefix} ${label1} ${suffix} ${label2}`;

return (
  <>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <div className="container" aria-label={screenReaderText}>
      <div aria-hidden="true">{label1}</div>
      <div aria-hidden="true">{label2}</div>
    </div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </>
);
```

The two nested `div` should not be available to the accessibility API; hence the use of `aria-hidden="true"`. The `div` with `className="container"` should be navigable by arrow keys when using JAWS. Moreover, when navigating to the container `div`, JAWS should read out a label which is a combined and modified text of the contents the two inner `div`.

The navigation flow should be: `h1` -> container `div` -> `footer`

I am guessing I should apply an appropriate `role` to the container `div`. The `tree` role gives the desired effect, but reading about it suggests that it is not best practice for this use case.

Comment: This doesn’t make sense to me. In your example, the container is completely empty for AT. Then, the arrow keys are already used by Jaws to read content, so if you actually put something inside the container, it would be read already. To Jaws users, application-like arrow key interaction would only be expected for focus navigation inside a component after entering it by means of tabs.

Comment: Hi @Andy, I did not fully understand what you meant by "AT" in the second sentence. The reason I am doing it this way is because when JAWS focus on the outer `div`, it should read out a text which is combined and modified version of the texts within the inner `div`. That's an aspect I'm sill looking into as well. I would have to find the correct `aria-*`.

Comment: Can you please provide more code to make your use case more apparent? Does it correspond to any [known pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/)?
AT=Assistive Technology, including screen readers. In your example, the container *is not focusable*. As slugolicious mentioned, there is a difference in how screen readers navigate: forms mode (what I called application-like focus navigation) and browse mode. You do not need to do anything for (accessible) texts inside the container to be read in browse mode. And forms mode only makes sense if the container offers any interaction.

Comment: I have edited the question and example code snippet to provide more information on the final goal I am trying to achieve.

Comment: There’s still an important open question: Does the container offer any interaction? Or do you simply expect it to being read?

Comment: Also, just to make sure we're not missing something obvious, a screen reader user can already use the down arrow key to navigate to every DOM element so you don't have to code that behavior. There are other ways to navigate with a screen reader too, such as by headings, lists, tables, landmarks, etc. As long as you use semantic HTML (`<h2>` for headings, `<ul>` for lists, etc), then you'll get that screen reader behavior for free.  So is there a reason why you'd want a non screen reader user to navigate with the down arrow?

Comment: @Andy The container should only be read; the inner elements should not be navigable.

Comment: @Slugolicious The aim is that **only** a screen reader user should be able to navigate to the container `div` using arrow keys. I understand that `div` is a non-semantic element and as such is not navigable by JAWS unless the `div` contains a text node, which in my use case it does not. Replacing the `div` with a semantic html element would work but I don't think any would be suitable for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid confusion about “navigating” the element: You want a screen reader to read the text in browse mode like regular text, which JAWS already does by means of the arrow keys, line by line.

Also, the whole text *Prefix Label1 Suffix Label2* should be in a single line, even though it’s visually presented in separate lines.

If you want text to be exposed *only* to assistive technology like screen readers, the famous `visually-hidden` CSS class comes into play (fka `sr-only`).

There’s a great explanation on how it works by [Scott O'Hara: Inclusively Hidden](https://www.scottohara.me/blog/2017/04/14/inclusively-hidden.html)

```css
/* ie9+ */

.visually-hidden:not(:focus):not(:active) {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Heading</h1>
<div className="container">
  <div class="visually-hidden">Prefix Label1 Suffix Label2</div>
  <div aria-hidden="true">Label1</div>
  <div aria-hidden="true">Label2</div>
</div>
<footer>Footer</footer>
```

### Why not `aria-label`?

The *accessible name* of an element, provided by means of `aria-label` or `aria-labelledby` is not announced in browse mode (when reading).

It is only used to build the lists of, f.e. headlines or landmarks, and in form mode, when navigating with <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

By default, the accessible name is built from the text contents, so using `visually-hidden` is taken into account, should you add a role or interaction.

### Mismatch between visual and accessible text

Since the text in your question is probably not the one used in production, I’d like to point out that it’s important to not divert too much between visual text and text accessible to assistive technology.

A lot of screen reader users are sighted, and rely on the two matching.

For example, visually presenting the two labels in two separate lines creates the expectation for JAWS users that they’d need to use <kbd>arrow down</kbd> twice, not once.

Also, how are sighted users making sense of the two labels without a screen reader, if prefix and suffix are missing?

Comment: With regards to the question about the mismatch between visual and accessible text, the visible text changes colour. As users with visual impairment would not be able to see the change in colour, the prefixes and suffixes are being added.

Comment: I see. Using colour only to distinguish things is another anti-pattern in accessibility. There’s a lot of people who cannot distinguish certain colours, but have otherwise excellent sight. Most of them don’t use screen readers. So you’d usually use an icon in addition. See [Understanding Success Criterion 1.4.1: Use of Color of the WCAG](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/use-of-color.html)

Comment: I have tried the implementation suggested in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-sunset-w68945?file=/src/App.js). I am aiming for a different behaviour. When using JAWS, the `div` with `class="container"` is still not navigable using arrow keys. And the different `label*` variables are not being read out. The final goal is when I navigate to the `div` with `class="container"`, it would read all the `label*` and `suffix*` together.

Comment: Oh you are right. I fixed the code. I forgot to remove the hidden properties after deciding to not use the additional variable.

Comment: Can you please be more precise when you say “navigate”. Arrow keys make JAWS read out content. Is that what you are aiming for? Is it reading out your Heading? And after that, what does Arrow Down read out?

Comment: For the above code snippet, the aim is for JAWS to read `Heading` -> `Prefix Label1 Suffix Label2` -> `Footer` where **->** represents a down arrow keystroke. Currently it's reading as `Heading` -> `Prefix` -> `Label1` -> `Suffix` -> `Label2` -> `Footer`. The idea to read all the labels and prefixes/suffixes together without having to press the down arrow in-between.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247946/discussion-between-aikind-and-andy).

Answer (score 1):

What are you navigating **to** when in the `<div>` if the child elements have `aria-hidden="true"`?

If you want the arrow keys to work then you need a [`role`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#role_definitions) on your `<div>` that will cause JAWS (or NVDA) to automatically switch from browse mode to forms mode.  The valid roles that do that are listed here: https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/keyboard-interface/#x6-1-fundamental-keyboard-navigation-conventions

Comment: Thanks. I've found that using `role="tree"` with `aria-label` meets the specifications, but I doubt I'm using the `tree` role in the correct context.

Comment: I have added a comment in the original question for the reason behind it. It should not navigate to anything inside the `div`. The flow should be `h1` -> `div` with `container` class -> `footer`

Comment: I'm with @andy. Your use case doesn't make sense or doesn't have enough detail. Are you trying to allow the user, whether a screen reader user or not, to navigate through the DOM elements using the arrow keys? If so, what's the reason for that? Arrow keys (for non screen reader users) should be reserved for interactive elements where an arrow key navigation makes sense, such as a tree (as you mentioned), a tab control, a combobox, a listbox, etc. I'm not seeing anything like that in your question.

Comment: I agree the original question did not convey the idea clearly. I have now edited the question and the example code snippet.